# Prometheus Exporter for SNMP targets

Tags: prometheus, snmp, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to get SNMP metrics from target system to prometheus, I am able to install it in my server and able to access that in web browser.

`http://3.X.X.X:9116/`

But when i provide target server info and trying to get that metrics, i am getting below error.

`ts=2023-07-18T15:39:24.510Z caller=collector.go:409 level=info auth=public_v2 module=if_mib target=3.X.X.X msg="Error scraping target" err="error getting target 3.X.X.X: request timeout (after 3 retries)"`

Seeing the same error in both browser and also in SNMP exporter.

Comment: Since the log showed an SNMP v2 request failed, you can use a tool like Wireshark to analyze further while reproducing the error. This has nothing to do with programming, and you should involve your network administrators.